# Changing background color for part of image in Open CV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am able to extract data from image where it is having white background, data with black background I am not able to extract. How to get this data.

[image]

Below is the code I tried but not working..

```
#denoise
#For normal image
#img = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img, None, 3, 3, 7, 21)

#gray
#img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Morp operation
#kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
#img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
#img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
```

Comment: Is the position of the darker area always the same?

Comment: Yes. Position may very slightly differ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach that inverts the color of big dark areas using `cv2.findContours` and `cv2.boudingRect`

```py
#denoise
#For normal image
img = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img, None, 3, 3, 7, 21)

#gray
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Morp operation
kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

#Transforms gray to white
img[img > 215] = 255

binary = cv2.bitwise_not(img)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for contour in contours:
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    # Ignore small areas
    if w*h < 500:
        continue

    # Invert colors
    img[y:y+h, x:x+w] = ~img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

# Transforms gray to white
img[img > 215] = 255
```

result:

[image: Filtered image]

Comment: how would I filter these images from other images having no black background, I need to  do this only for image having black ground. Text is also black so not able to filter it..

Comment: If I understand correctly it is inverting the text of non dark background areas? I don't know how those other images look like but you could change the `if w*h < 500` value

Comment: Also if that is the case, and your image input have different resolutions. instead of `if w*h < 500` as an absolute value you could do the following condition instead: if contour area is smaller than 5% of the total image size

Comment: I have other images where this black background is not present, I wanted to skip those images.. this code is running in loop. the code that you provided should only run for images having black background.

Comment: @ZKS Oh I see, If all dark areas are in the bottom, you could `np.mean` the bottom half of the image and see if its too dark. Maybe you could do that in the whole image too, but I think it would be harder to get the correct threshold (`img[y1:y2, x1:x2].mean()`)